# Popup dialog window based on selection in radio select list?

Tags: forms

Use case:

A radio select list with Option A and Option B.

When User selects Option A, a popup appears with specific "A" message to verify the selection before User saves the page.

When User selects Option B, a popup appears with specific "B" message to verify the selection before User saves the page.

Suggestion on how to develop this? Hoping there's a module.

Answer (score 0):

Since the popup appears as an immediate reaction to the user selection, this looks like a job for JavaScript or jQuery. Take a look at the jQuery [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) user interface. And here is a [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/171213) on working with JavaScript within Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Like argiepiano says, use jquery. There's a few ways you could do it. You could either put a listener on each element, or on the div. For example, if you have radio buttons in a div with id `edit-my-radios`:

```
$(.edit-my-radios).change(function () {
  alert("You have selected "+ $( this ).find(":selected").text());
}
```